# How can I batch copy certain files from multiple folders into multiple folders?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking to copy files that are like "MAN" that reside inside multiple folders in one directory into all the folders in another directory.

This is what I have now, it copies the files correctly but not into all the folders inside the directory. just into the directory itself.

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\test123\*") do @copy "%%~Fa\MAN*" /d "c:\Test Destination\*" 2>NUL
```

to reiterate the problem, the files are copied into c:\Test Destination* but I want it to copy to every folder in that folder. It would be great if the file already exists there, to not copy it at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the `source` and `target` folder trees identical?

Comment: Inside the source it is a folder structure like this -- 10.1, 10.2 ,10.3 and each have a couple files starting with MAN that I want to copy to the destination which is just a directory of folders with various names, it just needs to be copied into all of those folders.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, but is untested.  Test it on some sample files.

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\test123" %%a in (man*) do (
    pushd "c:\Test Destination"
        for /d /r %%b in (*) do if not exist "%%b\%%~nxa" copy "%%a" "%%b"
    popd
)
pause
```